# Windows Forms + CrossThread Messaging Exception

Tags: c#-4.0

In my project i have a class "C1" where i am continuously listening to clients, if any message received from client then i need to update my textbox text in form class. Am using delegate for this created in class "C1" and i used it in my form.cs in that function i am updating my textbox.

Please help me out

Comment: Not enough information from you. How you are listening to clients? Using HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use `Invoke` when assigning the `Text` property of your textbox, since updates to UI elements are only allowed from the main UI thread, and you are likely receiving your TCP communication messages on another thread.

You could do something like the following:

```
private void UpdateText(string text)
{
   if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
      textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => UpdateText(text)));
   else
      textBox1.Text = text;                     
}
```

which would check if the method is called on the UI thread, and if not pass the request to the UI thread before updating the text. If you need asynchronous behaviour you can use `textBox1.BeginInvoke` instead of `textBox1.Invoke`.

For more information see for example [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx).

Comment: but i am getting data in another class, from there am using delegate to update textbox, there am getting error, Please help me out

Comment: Can you post some of the code showing how you currently do this update?

Comment: My class is not inheriting Form class, but i am invoking Form Class listbox from normal c# class using delegates, how can i do this